# Loading views with out css and js with Angular and Node Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am building an app which uses Node and Angular routing. I want to handle all the routes in Angular.

Folder Structure:

- public

  - Images
  - css
  - js
  - partials

    - _search.html
    - home.html
  - index.html
- sass

  - all sass files (when compiled are going to public/css folder)

server.js

```
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use(sassMiddleware({
    // Options
    src: __dirname + '/sass',
    dest: __dirname + '/public',
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/css',  express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/js',  express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/images',  express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
app.use'/',function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(root_dir+'/public/index.html');
}
```

app.js (angular): I am using Angular ui-router for routing

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
         })
        .state('search', {
            url: "/search/:token",
            templateUrl: 'partials/_search.html'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404.html');

});
```

public/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <loads all css and javascript files>
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I do "http://localhost:3000", I am able to load home.html from partials, but when I do "http://localhost:3000/search/abcd", It loads the blank html with Menu Bar but couldn't load css/js/images and search.html partial.

```
On the node console, I see the following 404 errors:

example:
GET /search/js/index/mainPageSearchController.js 404 0.285 ms - 62
GET /search/js/index/exploreCitiesController.js 404 0.483 ms - 61
GET /search/js/strechy-main.js 404 0.355 ms - 44
```

My files are loading from search directory which is wrong.

Please suggest me what should be corrected to load the search.html from partials when "http://localhost:3000/search/abcd" is hit as per the above code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add the html from 'partials/_search.html' and the actual head html from 'index.html'. It seems like it may be a problem with your formatting in your html.

Comment: Yes, the header is in the public/index.html which is global page with menu bar.. I wanted to load "partials/search.html" in ui-view of index.html when "localhost:3000/search/abcd" is hit

Comment: what folder is your node server file stored in?

Comment: in the root folder, In ProjectFolder > Public (folder), server.js (node server), etc..